# perform a full server backup using ssh centos

Tags: centos, ssh, backup, hetzner

I have a dedicated server at hetzner and they told me the hard drives are broken and they must replace them with new ones.

I MUST back up all my websites and databases, that is my life work!

The problem is that hetzner does not offer support on how to backup.

They told me to access Hetzner Rescue System and I have mounted /dev/md2 to /mnt and I am stuck here.

How can I backup all my websites and databases from ssh?

I can not login to FTP or open my websites in a browser.

Please, this is urgent.

Thank you

Comment: Your life's work, eh? And somehow the idea of backing up your data hasn't come up prior to this?

Comment: i never thought the hard drives would break and stop working.

Comment: `1.` I hope you're able to get your data backed up safely and soundly. `2.` I hope you've learned something about the importance of backups.

Comment: @joeqwerty this is my first time backing up from ssh, so I have no idea how to do that. Where are my websites and databses located? Do I need to put those in a tar or zip and then use the link you gave me?

Comment: Everything built by humans eventually breaks and stops working. Sometimes without any prior warning. Backups protect you from this, but only if you _have_ them already when you need them! You will be fortunate to get your data back, and in future [make sure you have a backup system in place](http://serverfault.com/a/475868/126632) to protect your important work.

Comment: @MichaelHampton please, tell me, what should I do after mounting /dev/md2 to /mnt What is my next step in backing up using ssh?

Comment: @user1349390 Hire a professional to help you out. This is not an internet helpdesk. If you can't find someone, contact me at the email address listed in my profile and we'll work something out.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because SF is not a place to seek urgent help.

Comment: Hiring a professional to help you out of this is your only viable option at this point. However, it might very well be that he can't help either and you have to ship the disks to a data recovery firm (be prepared to shell out *a lot* o money for that).

Answer (score 1):

your lifes work, and you're backing it up only because a drive is failing ? o_O

there's very little information to go on here, but generally you'll want scp.

http://www.hypexr.org/linux_scp_help.php

Comment: hetzner told me the hard drives are broken and they need to be replaced. that's why I am backing up everything

Comment: this is my first time backing up from ssh, so I have no idea about everything. Where are my websites and databses located? Do I need to put those in a tar or zip and then use the link you gave me?

Comment: my point is, you needed a backup regardless of if their drives break or not.  but yes, you should be able to copy the file off the machine using ssh (scp specifically). The exact command depends on the filename of the zip on the remote machine.

Comment: @user1349390 regarding where it's located, it varies but for SQL you can use the mysqldump command (depending on the database size) to make a copy of your database to a degree and your site is PROBABLY under /var/www or /var/www/html

Answer (score 0):

You actually have multiple options, and in the future I hope that you setup some daily / weekly backups of your system.

Also, if you hosting provider is unable to clone your dives when they need to replace them in the hardware that you are renting from them, I would suggest you fins a better provider...

As mentioned by `Sirex`, you could use `SCP`, or even use `SFTP` which is FTP over ssh.

To do the latter, you can even use most FTP clients (such as `FileZilla`) that have support built in.

`scp` is a program acailable on most unix based machines, if your client happens to be windows, SFTP might be your best solution.