# Multi-OS imaging strategy

Tags: windows, centos, disk-image

I've been backup up my Windows system to an external 2TB WD drive for a while, but not my CentOS server. Most of the code I write lives on GitHub so I haven't been concerned about it. I'm currently working on setting up some machine learning services on my CentOS server and the setup and configuration is long and painful, so I've decided I need to start backing up my server too.

Currently I wake the Windows machine at 3AM and take the image, as I have 4 drives on it, and backup that image. Is there any benefits to moving my external backup drive (which is USB connected) to the server and use CentOS as the backup controller, or should I keep the drive connected to windows and backup the server to it?

If I leave the device where it is, my thought is that I'd like to adopt the same strategy, in that I'll take a disk image of the server and back that up over the network to the Windows machine.

Are there any issues with this approach? Is it better to use Windows to image the drive and send it across the network to CentOS?

Any other issues I should take into consideration?

Can I mount a network drive on the Windows machine that points to a folder on the CentOS machine that I can drop a backup image in?

I'm a developer not a sysadmin, so I know my way around my server, but I'm still getting used to administering it.

Thanks for any and all help.
Paul

Comment: A thought: any disk that's online is a copy, not a backup. Backups IMHO need to be offline, offsite, and incremental. This large protects you against fire, theft, malware, and human error. A USB disk in your home / office is vulnerable in many ways.

Comment: Related: [What's needed for a complete backup system?](https://serverfault.com/q/475849/126632)

Comment: Thanks Tim , I edited the title.