# How to make backup for the Local Server

Tags: windows, backup, network-attached-storage, disaster-recovery

I have critical server that running the local company system, that have system backup and company files and business documents with critical and important severity.

I'm planning to create a Network attached server, however this server weather its just a VM attached to another server or computer, or physical hard disk like multi Bay device attached to the network

Or create a cloud instance then sync the important files to be uploaded and make a frequent backup for the main server

What is the best approach to apply the Backup Server

1. Local Server that connected to network
2. Local VM that mirror the important data and store them in hard disks
3. Local & Cloud multi bay hard disk that sync the data and store them
   on the  cloud too
4. Online Cloud backup, install agent on the main server to sync the
   important files to be transfer for backup and archiving (Expensive
   solution)

Comment: We can't really tell you the "best" system because there isn't one. Everyone has different needs. What we can tell you is how to evaluate a backup system. The key is to [focus on restoring](https://serverfault.com/a/475868/126632) because that's the important part.

Comment: I need the method that used in similar company size, If I were in enterprise company I could make entire backup on the cloud and build 2 co-location for the backup but in this case I have limited budget